# how to download packages from a private nuGet host

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, package, nuget-package

I am very new to the nuget world. I have to use some private packages that are hosted in the private server. (I know the server URL). Could anyone tell me how to browse and download those package present in this private host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, click Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Settings. Select Package Sources and add your private server url in there. After that, when you click Manage Nuget Package for Solution, you will see drop down list on the right side with your private Nuget Server as a Package source. You can browse it the same as you browse nuget.org.

[image: Nuget Options]

[image: Manage package for solution]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I don't see anything getting populated on the right side of the screen. Any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: I added print screens to my answer. I hope that helps. Make sure you saved your changes and checkbox next to package source is selected.

Answer (score 0):

For all such purposes, NuGet supports setting up private package sources in the following ways:

- **Local feed**: Packages are simply placed on a suitable network file share, ideally using nuget init and nuget add to create a hierarchical folder structure (NuGet 3.3+). For details, see Local Feeds.
- **NuGet.Server**: Packages are made available through a local HTTP server. For details, see [NuGet.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/).
- **NuGet Gallery**: Packages are hosted on an Internet server using the [NuGet Gallery Project](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery). NuGet Gallery provides user management and features such as an extensive web UI that allows searching and exploring packages from within the browser, similar to nuget.org.